# Unique zero of an integral function

Tags: definite-integrals, roots

I am trying to prove the following statement: Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}_{++}$ be a continuously differentiable and strictly positive function.  Let $x_0\in (0,1)$. The function $g:[x_0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$:

$$g(x_1) = \int_{x_0}^1 f(t) dt - \int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(t) \left( 1+\frac{t-x_0}{x_1-x_0}\right) dt $$
has a single root on $[0,1]$. It might be helpful to note that: 
$$g'(x_1)=\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(t) \left(\frac{t-x_0}{(x_1-x_0)^2}\right)dt -2 f(x_1).$$

It is immediate that $g$ has an odd number of roots, but I cannot get a contradiction by assuming that it has more than 1.

Comment: Have you tried showing that $g' < 0$?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've tried, but that's not always true. That is, there are functions for which $g$ has a single root but $g'>0$ for some range of $x_1$: for instance, let $f$ be the pdf of some normal distribution centered at $x_0$ and with very low variance.